# Equivalent of subprocess.call() in C

Tags: python, c, windows, subprocess, clang

I wanted to try and rewrite my Python program in C, but am facing the issue of C not having an equivalent of subprocess.call().

Subprocess.call() runs a command and returns the exit code as 0 or 1, my program used that value to gauge whether a ping succeeded or failed, I need to replicate that in C.

I have found a few replacements but they use <sys/wait.h> and I am on Windows, not Linux.

Comment: Try `system()`. The return value is the exit status.

Comment: With `int system(char* s);` you can forward a command to the operating system while receiving the return value as an integer.